# How do you send G-code from a USB port with Python?

Tags: g-code, usb, python

I'm working on a project for my masters where I'm trying to detect print errors using object detection and I want to be able to pause the printer when a potential fault is detected. However I can't seem to figure out the correct way to send G-code to my printer from a Python script. Does anyone happen to know how this works?

Comment: I'm working on an identical project, I couldn't find any contact in your profile. If you want to discuss/share approaches let me know. Via SO chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6859185/nickdgreg or my github is in my profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is pretty straightforward, you open a serial connection and send the instructions over the serial connection. The printer reports "`OK`" when **received** (*not* when the command has been executed).

You can use pySerial to connect to a USB port with the correct speed, then send the command you want to execute (include the newline char).

You need to be aware that commands are [buffered](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#Buffering), if the buffer is full, the printer sends "OK" when there is a spot free in the buffer.

See [this question on a sister SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957089/how-to-send-one-gcode-command-over-usb).